# A shadow in a world without light ? Can you crack this riddle?

Tags: lighting

I have a plane with shadow catcher enabled and there are no lights in the scene and no background lighting but there is still a shadow represented in my viewer ???

Just curious why that is ..

Thank you all !!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could be off base, but when this happens in my scenes it's usually because of either;

the object has flipped normals
or the scale is inverted (which is kind of the same issue)